# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, plugin-wordpress

Pessoal estou fazendo um site no worpress e assim que instalei um plugin chamado Taylor Builder ele me retornou o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/storage/0/2b/cc/w2belocal/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tailor/includes/controls/abstract-control.php on line 260

Quando abro esse caminho direto via FTP e vou até a linha 260 está da seguinte forma:

```
<a class="button button-small js-default <% if ( 'undefined' == typeof showDefault || !showDefault ) { %>is-hidden<% } %>">
                        <?php _e( 'Default', 'tailor' ); ?>
                    </a>
```

Não sei o que posso mudar para funcionar, uma vez que sou leigo em back-end.
Acredito que esteja faltando alguma pontuação ou aspas, mas já tentei e não rolou.

Por gentileza, alguém sabe me dizer o que faz gerar esse erro?

Obrigado.

Comment: O que é estranho nesse trecho de código, é que tem tags ASP `<% e %>` dentro de um arquivo `.php`. Teria como postar o arquivo completo pra dar uma olhada ?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli fora que dentro das tags tem o uso de `typeof`, o que me faz pensar que isto ou é Javascript

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas se o PHP estiver com as diretivas "asp_tags"  ativada, vai dar Parser Error mesmo.